# How to encourage users to report data issues?

Tags: mobile, e-commerce, data-collection

Our product uses large amounts of third party data to sell products to our customers. Sometimes this data is really well structured, clean, and accurate. Other times, it's not so much. Images can be missing, descriptions can have typos (or be missing) other information can be wrong or out of date. Primarily, this service is consumed on a mobile app.

We were hoping to crowdsource the prioritization of fixing this bad data by asking our users to request we fix the data.

Have you seen any good examples of this? The only thing that comes to mind is google maps. Anything more mobile focused?

Comment: Hi David, can you clarify your question a little? Upon reading it I get a particular image/idea in my mind of your problem, but then I get to your comment about Google Maps and that totally confuses me as I can't see how Google Maps relates to your question?

Comment: Google maps gives you ability to suggest an edit

Answer (score 2):

Users in shopping mode tend to be rather passive, so I wouldn't require more than 1 click.

A simple, small textlink saying something like "This listing is missing information" in a corner of the product view would probably not alienate your third parties, but it would get you the data you need to point you to the content you may want to review.

Clicking the textlink could open a simple "Thank you" message that disappears after a second, but nothing more because you probably want your visitors to keep browsing and shopping.

Answer (score 0):

Quora comes to my mind. If I answer a question which is tagged to a topic not listed in my "Knows about" column, it asks for a bio for either of the topic after I'm done writing the answer. You can adapt similar idea and prompt the user to (re) enter the data if you think it needs improvement, by a short sweet quick pop-up. Sugarcoat it well.
Good luck!